# Prove by induction that $4n^2 + 1 < 3\cdot 2^n$ for every $n \ge 6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

My question is about solving for $k+1$

I did the base case and tried to solve the induction step.

this is what I tried

my hypothesis is $4k^2 + 1 < 3\cdot 2^k$ is true then I need to show that it is true for $k+1$

I did right hand side by doing this

$3\cdot2\cdot2^k = 3\cdot 2^{k+1}$ but I am not able to do left hand side
please help

Comment: I see no reason for the downvote.

Comment: You should ask this question in Maths StackExchange

Comment: this what i did

Comment: @NoorBoeing Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

HINT: multiplying $$3\cdot 2^n>4n^2+1$$ by $2$ we get
$$3\cdot 2^{n+1}>8n^2+2$$ and now show that $$8n^2+2>4n^2+8n+5$$ for $n>2$
so if we have $$3\cdot 2^{n+1}>8n^2+2$$ and $$8n^2+2>4n^2+8n+5$$ then is $$3\cdot 2^{n+2}>4(n+1)^2+1$$

Comment: this is what i did

Comment: Use induction to show $4n^2>8n+3$ for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: You might need to use the fact that $\forall a, a^2 \ge 0$

Comment: but i need to show. that 3⋅2^k+1>4(k+1)^2+1

Comment: The cases $n=0,1,2$ can easily proved

Comment: i dont know how to be good at solving induction problems related to inequalities

Answer (score 1):

For induction step assume

- $4n^2 + 1 < 3\cdot 2^n$

then

- $4(n+1)^2 + 1 =4n^2+1+8n+4\stackrel{I.H.}< 3\cdot 2^n+8n+4\stackrel{?}<3\cdot2^{n+1}$

$$3\cdot2^n+8n+4<3\cdot2^{n+1}=6\cdot2^{n}\iff 3\cdot2^n>8n+4$$

which is true for $n\ge 4$ (it can be proved by induction again).

Thus we need to verify the base case for $n_0\ge 4$.

Comment: where did 8n+ 4 came

Comment: @NoorBoeing For induction step we need to prove that $4(n+1)^2 + 1 < 3\cdot 2^{n+1}$ then we start from $4(n+1)^2 + 1=4(n^2+2n+1)+1=4n^2+1+8n+4$ and then apply the hypotesis.

Comment: thank u alot :)))

Comment: @NoorBoeing You are welcome, let me know if you can solve completely or for any other doubt.

Comment: i know how to solve cases where we have 2^n > n but when ever there is a number multiplying by it or adding i get confuse like 3*2^n or 8n + 4.

Comment: @NoorBoeing you can apply induction again to prove induction step, let try

Comment: u mean prooving 3*2^n > 8n+ 4?

Comment: @NoorBoeing yes exactly, it can be also proved by induction

Comment: i got that, but im confused about handing case where i have +4 in it

Comment: @NoorBoeing It is not a problem. The main problem is solved if $3\cdot 2^n > 8n+ 4$ is true right? then prove it: 1) Base case n=4 we have 3*16=48>36 ok - 2) Induction step: assume $3\cdot 2^n > 8n+ 4$ true and prove $3\cdot 2^{n+1} > 8(n+1)+ 4$

Comment: i did this so far 3*2^n+1 > 16n + 8 > ? i  am confused next step

Comment: @NoorBoeing We have to prove $3\cdot 2^{n+1} > 8(n+1)+ 4$ then start with LHS $$3\cdot 2^{n+1} =2\cdot 3\cdot 2^n \stackrel{I.H.}> 16n+8\stackrel{?}>8(n+1)+4\iff 16n + 8 >8n+12 \iff 8n>4$$

Comment: i seee the point, i am not confused on how to go about solving induction problems regarding inequalities. if you can teach me on what things to look when solving inequality that would be helpful

Comment: @NoorBoeing it is not simple give general advices on inequalities. If you have some specific issue let make a new OP on that. Is this OP solved?

Comment: i forgot to mention we have to proove for n >= 6

Comment: @NoorBoeing It’s ok, indeed it suffices to show by direct calculation that the base case for n=6 works, then induction step is fine since it’s true for $n\ge4$ and thus slso for $n\ge6$.

Answer (score 1):

$3\cdot2\cdot2^k = 3\cdot 2^{k+1}$

Okay, we have to bring $3*2^k > 4k^2 + 1$ into this.

$3*2*2^k > 2(4k^2 + 1)$

And we want to somehow relate this to $4(k+1)^2 + 1 = 4k^2 + 8k + 5$

So $3\cdot2^{k+1} = 2*3*2^k > 2(4k^2 + 1) = 8k^2 +2 = 4k^2 + 4k^2 + 2$

So we have to show that $4k^2 + 2 \ge 8k + 5$.  Which.... seems reasonable.

$k \ge 6$ so $4k^2 > 4*6*k$ and:

$3\cdot2^{k+1} = 2*3*2^k > 2(4k^2 + 1) = 8k^2 +2 = 4k^2 + 4k^2 + 2\ge 4k^2 + 24k + 2 = 4k^2 + 8k + 16k + 2$.

So now we just need to show $16k + 2 > 5$. That's..... well, that's.....

Again $k \ge 6$ so $16k \ge 16*6$.

$3\cdot2^{k+1} = 2*3*2^k > 2(4k^2 + 1) = 8k^2 +2 = 4k^2 + 4k^2 + 2\ge 4k^2 + 24k + 2 = 4k^2 + 8k + 16k + 2\ge 4k^2 + 8k + (16*6 + 2) > 4k^2 + 8k +4 + 1 = 4(k+1)^2 + 1$.

And that's the induction step.